# файл показан в КБ, как сделать чтобы показывал в МБ/ГБ

Tags: javascript, java

На фронте, при пересылке файла, он отображается в КБ, нашел ошибку, теперь надо понять как подставить в МБ

```
<FileChip
    dataTooltipName={dataTooltipName}
    uploadStatus={file && file.upload_status}
    fileName={file && (file.name || file.file_name || file.label)}
    size={file.sizeFile || Math.ceil(((file && (file.size || file.file_size )) /                        1024) || 0) + ' КБ'}
    progress={file && file.progress}
    read={read}
    icon={this.renderIconFile(file)}
    onClick={onClick}
    repeatUpLoad={this.repeatUpLoad}
/>
```

так же на беке нашел функцию, которая конвертирует в кб,мб,гб и тд.

```
public static String getDisplayFileSize(long size) {
    String measure = "";
    double calcSize = 0;
    if (size >= 0) {
        if (size < 1024)
            return Integer.toString((int) size) + " Байт";

        calcSize = (double) size;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            calcSize /= 1024;
            if (calcSize < 1024) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        measure = " КБ";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        measure = " МБ";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        measure = " ГБ";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        measure = " ТБ";
                        break;
                    default:
                        measure = " Очень больших байт";
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

то есть он грубо говоря 20мб показывает 194124кб типа того

Comment: так в чем проблема?

Comment: ну проблема в том, что как бы не менял size, он либо не показывает 0 кб, либо показывает 2000000кб

Comment: вообще у вас нет `return` в конце, сейчас ответ напишу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема как и говорил была в 
size={file.sizeFile || Math.ceil(((file && (file.size || file.file_size )) /                        1024) || 0) + ' КБ'}

просто поменял file.sizeFile на  displaySize(т.е. правильный метод с бэка)

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение вопроса:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(getDisplayFileSize(1048576 * 2));
    }
    public static String getDisplayFileSize(long size) {
        String measure = "";
        double calcSize = 0;
        if (size >= 0) {
            if (size < 1024) {
                return Integer.toString((int) size) + " Байт";
            } else {
                calcSize = (double) size;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    calcSize /= 1024;
                    if (calcSize < 1024) {
                        switch (i) {
                            case 0:
                                measure = " КБ";
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                measure = " МБ";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                measure = " ГБ";
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                measure = " ТБ";
                                break;
                            default:
                                measure = " Очень больших байт";
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return Integer.toString((int) calcSize) + measure;
            }
        }
        return  "Nan";
    }
}
```

Comment: это на клиентской части косяк. С бэком все впорядке. Косяк в строке size={